# Optimal Sentinel 2 Bands combination for NDMI

Tags: qgis, remote-sensing, sentinel-2

I want to calculate NDMI (Normalized Difference Moisture Index) using Sentinel 2 bands on QGIS. I am not sure if right formula is B8-B11 or B8A - B11. Band 8 seems to give better results but on the other hand band 8A is reported more often in papers.

Is there any expert who can help?

Answer (score 5):

The NDMI was designed to be used with wavelengths 820nm (NIR) and 1600nm (SWIR). Band 8 has a central Wavelength of 832.9nm and band 8A has 864.0nm (https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/missions/sentinel-2/instrument-payload/resolution-and-swath). Therefore, band number 8 looks like the most adequate.

The Index DataBase supports this choice as well: https://www.indexdatabase.de/db/i-single.php?id=56